# set encoding for Text data type in app engine data store

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

In my android project with app engine backend, I am using Text data type for storing one of my entity properties. As Text data type is not Unicode supported unlike String data type, my encodings are getting lost and while retrieving the data for that property from the data store. Hence I can only see ascii characters and all others are not displaying properly. How can I set Unicode encoding for the Text data type? Any help is appreciated.

Please refer the code below where I am populating my text data type (quizcontent) and storing it in the app engine data store. I am getting the content from a locally stored file, populating into a string and then loading that string into my quizcontent property (of data type Text) in the app engine data store. When I view this property in the the data store from app engine console, I can see that the Unicode encoding is getting lost.

```
 public class EndpointsInsertUpdateQuizContentTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long>{
protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts){
    Quizcontenttableendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Quizcontenttableendpoint.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { } });
    Quizcontenttableendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();
    try{
        //get local file content into a string
        int ch;
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
        FileInputStream fis;
        //String quizContentString;
        fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput(selectedQuiz);
        while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
            fileContent.append((char)ch);
        String quizContentString = new String(fileContent);

            QuizContentTable quizContentTable = new QuizContentTable();
            quizContentTable.setQuizKey(quizKey);
            quizContentTable.setQuizContent(quizContentString);

            quizContentResult = endpoint.insertQuizContentTable(quizContentTable).execute();
    }   
    catch(Exception e){
        errMsg=e.toString();}
    return (long) 0;
}
private ProgressDialog pdia;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
    super.onPreExecute();
    pdia = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    pdia.setMessage("Loading");
    pdia.show();    
}
protected void onPostExecute(Long result1) {
    pdia.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issues. The problem was that I had missed out UTF encoding while reading the file content into the string. Replaced the filereading part in my code above with the below code

> ```
>           String str;
>             StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
>             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getBaseContext().openFileInput(selectedQuiz), "UTF-8"));
>             while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
>                 fileContent.append(str);
>             String quizContentString = new String(fileContent);
>             in.close();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a encoding property with your text parameters [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Text